# ORACLE: convert VARCHAR to TIMESTAMP/TIMEZONE

Tags: sql, oracle, date-format

Any suggestions on how I can convert a `VARCHAR` of format `2016-03-24T11:31:31+0100` into `timestamp/time zone`

"FIELD_YYY" which was obviously once a timestamp with time zone
is fed to "TABLE_XXX" and I have to use this field from this table for my uses.

(I believe the T marks the start of the time part when timestamp is converted to VARCHAR)

I need to convert this back to timestamp/time zone.

```
select to_timestamp('2016-03-24T11:31:31+0100', 'yyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from DUAL
```

No I can't change the "FIELD_YYY" or "TABLE_XXX", WHY? I just can't, that's life... :-(

Answer (score 4):

Use `to_timestamp_tz()` function, enclose "T" in double quotes in the format string and you are good to go.

```
select to_timestamp_tz('2016-03-24T11:31:31+0100'
                     , 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:mi:sstzhtzm') as res
  from dual
```

result:

```
RES                                  
--------------------------------------
24-MAR-16 11.31.31.000000000 AM +01:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use to_timestamp_tz

```
select to_timestamp_tz(your_string, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM') from dual;

select to_timestamp_tz('2011-05-12 19:04:41.032645 +01:00',
      'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM') from dual;
```

Comment: That doesn't handle the 'T' character.